# Improper integral $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I wonder how to figure it out this integral: $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{dx}{x \sqrt{x^2 - 1}}$$. What I know is: $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{dx}{x\sqrt{(x+1)(x-1)}}$$, but what does this help me to figure it out the entire integral? Please help ...

Answer (score 7):

By making the substitution $x\to1/x$, we have
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2-1}}
=\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\bigg[\arcsin x\bigg]_0^1=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Comment: Can you show me more steps, how did you come to this answer? ;)

Comment: @user124942 What part of the answer is unclear? Be specific and I will be happy to explain.

Comment: This part when you wrote: By making the substitution $x \rightarrow \dfrac{1}{x}$ ...

Comment: Take $u=\frac 1x \implies -x^2 du =dx $ . Make the sub and you will see.

Comment: I get it. I made an integral $$\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}\mathrm{d}x = \left[\arcsin{x}\right]_{0}^{1} = \arcsin(1) - \arcsin(0) = \dfrac{\pi}{2} - 0 = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$$.

Comment: I solved also for $u = \sqrt{x^2 - 1}$ and get the integral $\bigg[\arctan x\bigg]_0^{\infty}$

Answer (score 0):

But, if you take $u = \sqrt{x^2 -1}dx$ and make a substitution, you get the integral of $\tan^{-1}(u)\Big|_{0}^{\infty} = \tan^{-1}(\infty) - \tan^{-1}(0) = \frac{\pi}{2} - 0 = \frac{\pi}{2}$ which means, that this integral is convergent. ;)